# Python multiple requests with unique ID for each request

Tags: python, json, request

I would like to know what the way to send several API requests where each request has a unique ID.

So, first of all I get a json file from the first API request:

`url1 = 'https:// 10.200.35.14:8443/oms1350/data/npr/physicalConns?wdmConnectionType=WdmPortType_ots'`

and then I get a json file:

`physical_conn = pd.read_json(url)`

one of the information from this json file is the ID, so each entry of this json file has an ID entry, like this (peace part of response):

```
"aseLongLinkStatus": "AseLongLinkSupported_no",
"id": 11625,
"key": "PhysicalConn/11625",
```

and the next one request is to get the second json file with the second URL request, but now I would like to send this URL request passing the ID got on previous URL request, like this:

`url2 = 'https:// 10.200.35.14:8443/oms1350/data/npr/physicalConns/' + id + '/fiberCharacteristic'`

and then generate a second json file with this second URL request.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use api requests 'axios'. You can install axios module, must import to your js file.

And api request like that:

```
var id_s = [1,2,3,4,5]
const url1 = 'https:// 10.200.35.14:8443/'

for(let id in id_s){
aixos.get(url1 + 'oms1350/data/npr/physicalConns/' + id_s[id]+ 
'/fiberCharacteristic').then(response=>{

     // whatever want you do response
})
}
```

You can do same thing for url2.

Comment: Thanks sudesanlii, but I think that there is a kinf of mistake in your explanation, thay why I could not run the first line of, I got an issue: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Could you please explain better?

Comment: I changed it. Array of id_s updated. And in axios get request, id-> id_s[id] 

'id' is an index; like 0,1,2,3,4,5...... But id_s[id] is actual value of array. (1,2,3,4,5) 

With this loop, the url you want is in order:

----'https:// 10.200.35.14:8443/oms1350/data/npr/physicalConns/1/fiberCharacteristic'
----'https:// 10.200.35.14:8443/oms1350/data/npr/physicalConns/2/fiberCharacteristic'
.....
----'https:// 10.200.35.14:8443/oms1350/data/npr/physicalConns/5/fiberCharacteristic'